# Can knowledge of $\int f(x)^2 dx$ possibly be used in obtaining $\int f(x) dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I have three problems of the form

$\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}} f(x) \, dx$,

where

$f(x)=-2 \sqrt{9 x+1} \sqrt{21 x-4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{x (9 x+1)}+1}$,
and $f(x)=-42 x \sqrt{9 x+1} \sqrt{21 x-4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{x (9 x+1)}+1}$ and $f(x)=8 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{9 x+1} \sqrt{x (9 x+1)} \sqrt{21 x-4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{x (9 x+1)}+1}$.

Mathematica does not solve these integration problems, but readily does the problems of the form $\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}} f(x)^2 \, dx$, yielding $\frac{2 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}\right)}{9 \sqrt{3}}$, $\frac{49}{648} \left(6+\sqrt{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}\right)\right)$ and $\frac{4}{3}-\frac{\log \left(7+4 \sqrt{3}\right)}{9 \sqrt{3}}$, respectively.

Can these observations be employed in any manner in solving the original three problems, or can these three problems be solved directly (transformation of variables,...), despite Mathematica's failure to do so?

Of course, the indefinite integrations $\int f(x)^2 \, dx$ can also be solved, yielding 
$4 \left(63 x^3+15 x^2-\frac{\sqrt{x (9 x+1)} \left(216 x^2+42 x+1\right)}{6 \sqrt{3}}+x+\frac{\log \left(18 x+6 \sqrt{x (9 x+1)}+1\right)}{36 \sqrt{3}}\right)$ and $1764 \left(\frac{189 x^5}{5}+\frac{15 x^4}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{x (9 x+1)} \left(279936 x^4+42768 x^3+216 x^2-30 x+5\right)}{12960 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{\log \left(18 x+6 \sqrt{x (9 x+1)}+1\right)}{15552 \sqrt{3}}\right)$ and $192 \left(\frac{1701 x^5}{5}+\frac{459 x^4}{4}+13 x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{x (9 x+1)} \left(279936 x^4+81648 x^3+6696 x^2+30 x-5\right)}{1440 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{\log \left(18 x+6 \sqrt{x (9 x+1)}+1\right)}{1728 \sqrt{3}}\right)$, respectively.

Per the comment of "uniquesolution", the NIntegrate command with WorkingPrecision->32 gives -0.19559399958899403861456602832005, -0.41995514862765510309782111510810, and 0.58218377818878373916321174945773, respectively. From the quantum-information-theoretic context, from which these problems stem  https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09228, I strongly suspect/hope that these 
numerical results correspond to rather simple exact expressions (possibly involving inverse hyperbolic functions, such as $\sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}\right))$. But the WolframAlpha site https://www.wolframalpha.com (my usual recourse in such matters) does not seem to discern them.

The third numerical value given in the previous paragraph is clearly equal to the first value plus $\frac{7}{9}$. So, we have (taking the difference of the two integrands) that $\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}} 2 \sqrt{9 x+1} \sqrt{21 x-4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{x (9 x+1)}+1} \left(4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{x (9
   x+1)}+1\right) \, dx= \frac{7}{9}$. Can this be formally demonstrated?
(See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338679/prove-that-a-certain-integration-yields-the-value-frac79 for an affirmative answer to this question, and an apparent route to solving the three initial problems of this question.)

Comment: I suspect the answers to your questions are "no" and "no". You will have to rely on numerical methods.

Comment: The function NIntegrate in Mathematica will provide excellent numerical approximations.

Comment: if you have the equation resulting from the indefinite integral, then differentiating it should give you f(x). I mean: Let $K(x)=\int f^{2}(x)dx$, then $\frac{d}{dx}K(x)dx=f^{2}(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcoth}{arcoth}$$
Let
$$\begin{align}
3x &= u^2 &9x+1&=v^2\text{,}
\end{align}$$
and stereographically project the curve $v^2-3u^2=1$ about $(u,v)=(0,1)$ so that
$$\frac{v-1}{u}=\frac{3u}{v+1}=m\text{.}$$
Then the integrands reduce to rational expressions in $m$, and the integrals are given by 
$$-\frac{1}{27}\left(3 +2\sqrt{3}\arcoth{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
$$-\frac{7}{81}\left(6 -\sqrt{3}\arcoth{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
$$\frac{2}{27}\left(9 -\sqrt{3}\arcoth{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Comment: Fabulous! For a highly distinct transformative approach to these problems see the answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338679/prove-that-a-certain-integration-yields-the-value-frac79 (Of course, I'm happy to have the three specific problems of immediate interest to me solved--but still must admit that the answer to the specific question in the title is negative--but "by hook-or-by-crook".)

Comment: I would appreciate a more detailed step-by-step presentation of the argument. Superficially, it seems that one is transforming a univariate problem to a bivariate one, with questions arising about appropriate jacobians to employ. I guess the key concept is stereographic projection. How does one get back from the (bivariate) integrands with the pair of variables (u,v) to (univariate) integrands with just m?

Comment: $\tfrac{v-1}{u}=\tfrac{3u}{v+1}=m$ gives two equations with two unknowns $(u,v)$—its geometric significance is that a line of slope $m\neq 0$ through $(0,1)$ passes through exactly one other point of the hyperbola $v^2-3u^2=1$ and viceversa. The solution gives $(u,v)$ as a rational function of $m$, and consequently $x$ is also given as a rational function of $m$.

Comment: Well, I played around with this, to put it in my usual way of thinking, and it seems that the indicated transformation is $x\to \frac{4 m^2}{3 \left(m^2-3\right)^2}$, with a jacobian of $\frac{8 m \left(m^2+3\right)}{3 \left(m^2-3\right)^3}$ and limits of integration 0 and 1.